# Как реализовать асинхронное взаимодействие приложений

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

Необходимо, чтобы одно приложение могло создать событие, а другое отдельное приложение, принять его, среагировать, что-то типа как клиент-сервер, но не совсем, а что-то типа как на JS мы создаем функцию типа на `OnClick` и когда событие происходит, запускается эта функция и обрабатывает его.

Скажите в какую сторону копать, может есть какой-то пример?

Цель - создать механизм уведомлений, как в новой Windows 10, но чтобы также работало на более старых версиях Делфи.

Comment: `принять его, среагировать` - IPC ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/interprocess-communications ) . Выбирайте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `RegisterWindowMessage`
- `WM_USER` \ `WM_APP` \  `WM_COPYDATA`
- `SendMessage`

Вот те три вещи которые вам нужны =)

а именно  `SendMessage` `WM_COPYDATA`

Comment: это будет работать везде? на всех win ? xp - 10

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг, почему нет? Из справки: *RegisterWindowMessage: Minimum supported client Windows 2000 Professional [desktop apps only]*

Comment: чет читаю, а с помощью всего этого можно текст произвольный передать, а не просто числа? пытаюсь хороший примерчик найти и опробовать

Comment: Можно. http://www.sql.ru/forum/273943/peredacha-teksta-cherez-soobshheniya-windows

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг [WM_COPYDATA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/wm-copydata) (а пример на Delphi [тут](https://bitbucket.org/sas_team/sas.planet.src/src/default/Test/TestWMCopyData/TestWMCopyData.dpr)).

Comment: @zed промер на делфи скомпилировал, но так и не понял а где приемный код, этот как я понял для передачи

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг Код получения вот [тут](https://bitbucket.org/sas_team/sas.planet.src/src/050c5ef46487304e318b551352312a772435833a/Src/MainForm/frm_Main.pas#lines-3799).

Comment: спасибо, написал сам приложение для приема сообщения, вопрос, там когда мы отправляем сообщение всегда указываем заголовок окна... можно ли делать широковещательное сообщение? для всех ?

Comment: все разобрался $FFFF всем спасибо!

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг  `это будет работать везде?` Нет. Вернее - везде, но не всегда из-за ограничений UIPI. Грубо говоря - "обычное" приложение таким образом не достучится до запущенного от администратора.

Comment: @kami, _обычное приложение таким образом не достучится до запущенного от администратора_ - что-то не то вы сказали, по-моему. 'WM_COPYDATA' работает во всех Windows, начиная с 3.0 точно (не удивлюсь, если с 1.0). На нем основано практически все межпроцессное взаимодействие, в частности OLE и забытый нынче DDE. Посылка 'WM_COPYDATA' любому приложению не требует поднятия привилегий. Во-первых, потому что это абсолютно не нужно, а во-вторых, от такого весь COM и COM+ перестал бы работать. Вплоть до заурядного буфера обмена.

Comment: @freim Вы не правы. Рекомендую внимательно прочитать https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage , пояснение про параметр HWND.

Comment: @kami, да, верно, как-то я это просмотрел. Причем буфер обмена нормально копирует из поднятой программы в обычную. Интересно могут ли общаться локальные out-of-proc COM серверы разных уровней, если я правильно помню, там все идет через WM_COPYDATA.